# What is the name of the piano technique when a player dramatically slams the pianos lower/bass keys?

Tags: piano, technique

It's like slapping the lowest part of the piano, like a thunder/rumble/booming-like effect. I've seen on wiki that it may be called "bashing"? How do you achieve it?

Here's a video of it being using multiple times, towards the ending

Comment: Elton John used that to great effect in the song Bennie And The Jets.

I have seen him perform live. It's a powerful thing when blasting through thousands of watts of PA system.

Answer (score 1):

*Fortissimo*

Or triple forte - *fortississimo* - I suppose is the proper thing to mean *as loud as possible.*

In that particular recording it sounds like there is a bass drum or some other percussion also being used. That seems to be what is producing the big thud.